# Best practices for using Azure CDN in scenarios that require authentication to access?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-cdn, azure-appservice, azure-front-door

I've never configured a CDN before and I'm looking for guidance for how to approach the configuration for my scenario.

For context, I'm  currently using Azure Verizon Premium CDN and an Azure App service (.Net Core). My authentication platform is Azure Active Directory.

I have a static web app that has lots of static content (hundreds of files). Users hit the website at (`www.mysite.azurewebsites.net/index.html`). Index.html then fetches large amounts of static content (various, images, video, metadata). Initially, the requirement was to just serve the content publicly but now I have requirements around restricting access to some the content based on whether or not a user has a certain role & the user hits a certain path. I also need to be able to keep some content public and highly available to end users.

Before authorization requirements came in, I was able to successfully set up a CDN endpoint (`www.mysite-cdn.azureedge.net`) and point it to my app service no problem! I can hit the site and see the site content from the cdn endpoint without auth no issue.

Problems came when I added authentication to my site my CDN is redirected during the authentication flow back to the origin endpoint. The origin authentication middleware (Nuget: `Microsoft.Identity.Web`) automatically assembles the callback uri for AAD as "`www.mysite.azurewebsites.net/signin-oidc`". So the present flow for a user hitting the CDN endpoint returns them to an error page on the app service endpoint. Although if they manually redirect to "www.mysite.azurewebsites.net" they are logged in, I don't want to redirect the user back to origin, I want to keep them on [www.mysite-cdn.azurewebsites.net](http://www.mysite-cdn.azurewebsites.net).

Essentially, I want to be able to enable these flows:

- Public End User -> CDN Endpoint + Public  path -> (CDN request origin and caches) -> End user sees site at CDN endpoint
- Internal End User -> CDN Endpoint + Private  path -> (CDN request origin and has access) -> User is permitted into site at CDN endpoint
- Internal End User -> CDN Endpoint + Private  path -> (CDN request origin and DOESN’T have access) -> User is redirected to public CDN endpoint (or unauthorized page)

This is the auth check for each static file in OnPrepareResponse for static file options. This checks authentication before requesting a static asset in this folder on the server. This works fine without the CDN. It should be noted that I also do role checks and this has been simplified for the sake of the example as it repos with Authentication.

```
OnPrepareResponse = staticContext =>
                {
                    // require authentication
                    if (authenticate && 
                        !staticContext.Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                    {
                        // Redirect back to index sign in page all unauthorized requests
                        staticContext.Context.Response.Redirect(unauthenticatedRedirectPath);
                    }
                },
```

I did find this stack overflow which seemed similar to my problem however I am using a different NuGet package (`Microsoft.Identity.Web`). I implemented a check to redirect however that did not seem to work and cause an infinite loop when trying to login.

```
Action<MicrosoftIdentityOptions> _configureMsOptions = (options) =>
            {
                options.Instance = Configuration["AzureAd:Instance"];
                options.Domain = Configuration["AzureAd:Domain"];
                options.ClientId = Configuration["AzureAd:ClientId"];
                options.TenantId = Configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"];
                options.CallbackPath = Configuration["AzureAd:CallbackPath"];
                options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = async (context) =>
                {
            // This check doesn’t work because the request host always is mysite.azurewebsites.net in this context
                   //  if (context.Request.Host.Value.Contains("mysite-cdn")) 
                   // {
                        context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = "https://" + "mysite-cdn-dev.azureedge.net/" + Configuration["AzureAd:CallbackPath"];
                    //}
                };
            };
```

I've started looking into Azure Front door, as that seems to be more applicable to my use case but haven't set it up. It provides some level of caching/POP as well as security. It looks like it's also possible to use with Azure AD with some web server tweaking. It would be good to know from others if Azure Front Door sounds like a more sensible CDN solution approach vs Azure CDN.

I've also looked into Azure CDN Token authentication- but that seems to be something that also requires me to stamp each request with an Auth token. It changes my architecture such that I can no longer just 'point' my cdn at the web app and instead my app would give the browser a token so it could securely request each asset.

All that said, I'm looking for guidance on how best to configure an application using a CDN while also using authentication. Thanks!

Comment: have you checked this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-token-auth

Comment: I've also looked into Azure CDN Token authentication- but that seems to be something that also requires me to stamp each request with an Auth token. It changes my architecture such that I can no longer just 'point' my cdn at the web app ... did I miss something? 'Token authentication verifies that requests are generated by a trusted site by requiring requests to contain a token value that holds encoded information about the requester.'